# Check if Windows Server 2019 has Windows Updates installed

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

How can I check if Windows Updates have been installed in Windows Server 2019 Standard?

We have Windows Server 2019 Standard, and Windows Update says that the last update was on 9/19/2019. According to Windows, no updates have been installed in over two years.

After asking around, I was told that IT disabled automatic Windows updates and that IT installs the Windows updates. Supposedly, the server is up-to-date. IT doesn't reply to emails or calls, so contacting them would be useless.

Is there another way to check if the Windows Updates have been applied?

This is what "Installed Updates" tells me:
[image]

Other Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The update history, which you posted, should display any and all Windows updates whether installed manually or automatically. Another method of checking is to open powershell and run `wmic qfe list`. This should list all of the updates including the HotFix (KB) number and link, description, comments, installed date, and more.

`get-wmiobject -class win32_quickfixengineering` is another option that should show less information from the first.

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/578769/check-whether-windows-updates-are-being-installed) is another thread that might prove useful.